# Generate Image barcode using java and save into mysql as url

Tags: java, mysql

```
public RackDTO createNew(RackDTO requestDTO) {
    Merchant currectMerchant = authService.getCurrentMerchant();

    // validates if in db rack name already exist
    Rack rackInDB = rackDAO.findByMerchantAndNameIgnoreCase(currectMerchant, requestDTO.getName()).orElse(null);
    if (rackInDB != null) {

        log.error("rack with name [{}] under merchant [{}] already exist");
        return null;
    }

    Rack newRack = modelMapper.map(requestDTO, Rack.class);
    newRack.setMerchant(currectMerchant);
    newRack.setTotalCell(requestDTO.getXaxis() * requestDTO.getYaxis());
    newRack.setStatus(GeneralStatus.ACTIVE);
    rackDAO.save(newRack);

    // TODO create corresponding cell records
    for (int i = 1; i <= requestDTO.getXaxis(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= requestDTO.getYaxis(); j++) {

            Cell newCell = new Cell();
            newCell.setMerchant(currectMerchant);
            newCell.setCellId("RK" + newRack.getId() + "CL" + i + j);
            newCell.setStatus(CellStatus.EMPTY);
            newCell.setRack(newRack);
            cellDAO.save(newCell);
        }
    }
    ;

    return modelMapper.map(newRack, RackDTO.class);
}
```

I want to generate barcode for each cell inside the for loop while generating **cell id**.

Any suggestion for free barcode library?

Comment: As a "general" recommendation, I'd avoid storing images in your database directly.  It would be better to store the "value" of the barcode and generate the image when required

Comment: Requesting suggestions for APIs is considered off topic, as they change way to fast - [A quick google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&ei=KAltW-fSLI2O8gWwp6NA&q=java+barcode+generator&oq=java+barcode+gen&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l5j0i22i30k1l5.4769.5211.0.6376.3.3.0.0.0.0.220.429.2-2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.429....0.GqqNIZpuZms) will provide you will a number of possible choices you could try

Comment: Any link suggestion. Some are trail version.

Comment: in that case can store image as a url?

Comment: A general method for "storing" images is to store the physical images in a directory somewhere, which accessible by the server and store the file path to it

Comment: Store image into aws s3 folder and save the url into mysql. i need generate barcode for the cell id. so any suggestion for that

Comment: Asking for libraries etc. is off-topic. Do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use many libraries for generating barcodes like Zxing and etc you can search it.

But avoid storing images on the database. You can save the content of a barcode and generate barcodes each time or you can save barcodes somewhere as a file on a memory storage.